# Dynamically allocating an array of pointers in C++

Tags: arrays, pointers, memory, dynamic, allocation

I'm writing a program that's supposed to look at an array of pointers that point to integers and then have the user enter a target , the program should then replace the targets that were found with 1's and the other values with 0's . I'm trying to dynamically allocate an array of pointers but it won't let me for some reason . I'm also having trouble returning the new array (after it's been modified) from the function so i can print it in main. I'm not that good with pointers yet so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

```
include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int* flagArray (int *p[], int n, int x)     
{   
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(x == *p[i])
        {
            *p[i] = 1;
        }
        else
            *p[i] = 0;
    }
    return *p; //Why wont this return the adresses of each of the 10 elements ? it only returns the adress of the first element.

}
void main()
{
    int const size = 10;
    int target;
    int *arr[] = new int*[size];    
    cout<<"fill the array : "<<endl;
    for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cin>>*arr[i];
    }
    cout<<"Enter the target : ";
    cin>>target;
    for(int j = 0;j<size;j++)
    {
    cout<<*(flagArray(arr,size,target))<<endl;  // works for first element only , rest are 0s since theyre not checked
    }
    delete []*arr;
}
```

Comment: this is just wrong on so many levels... you probably shouldn't juggle with dynamic arrays as you don't know what you're doing. How about good old `vector`?

Comment: @kareem If this is homework, are you prevented from using c++ standard library classes like `vector`?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes , i haven't taken that yet so if i use it they might deduct marks .

Comment: @KarolyHorvath can  you clarify why it's wrong on so many levels? it was working fine until i changed int *p to int *p[] as a parameter of the function and until i changed it from int arr[] to int *arr[] .

Comment: I think Karoly is referring to the fact that there is more than one issue. For instance you create an array of integer pointers (the creation is a bit suspect and surprised it compiles as is). If it were to create the array you still have to create (with `new`) space for each element in the array. So before `cin >> *arr[i];` you should do `arr[i] = new int;` . You should only have to call `flagArray` once and then loop over `arr[]`. No need for `flagArray` to return anything. Your array is modified directly by `flagArray`. Then at the bottom your `delete [] *arr` should be `delete []` ...

Comment: continued ... but before you delete the array you need to loop through each pointer in the array and call `delete` on it. I can't give anymore information than this beyond actually posting the revised code but that won't help you if you wish to be a programmer.